# Gem5 v21.2.1.0 build error with hdf5 begin() undefined reference

Tags: c++, g++, hdf5, scons, gem5

I was trying to build the gem5 v21.2.1.0 with default configuration and had this error. I could build previous versions of gem5 (v20/v19) without similar issues.

**g++:**

```
    :: g++ --version
    g++ (GCC) 10.1.0
```

**python:**

```
    :: python3 --version 
    Python 3.6.8
```

**Error Log:**

```
    :: python3 $(which scons) USE_HDF5=0 build/X86/gem5.opt -j8 
    scons: Reading SConscript files ...
    Checking for linker -Wl,--as-needed support... (cached) yes
    Checking for compiler -Wno-free-nonheap-object support... (cached) yes
    Checking for compiler -gz support... (cached) yes
    Checking for linker -gz support... (cached) yes
    Info: Using Python config: python3-config
    Checking for C header file Python.h... (cached) yes
    Checking Python version... (cached) 3.6.8
    Checking for accept(0,0,0) in C++ library None... (cached) yes
    Checking for zlibVersion() in C++ library z... (cached) yes
    Checking for C library tcmalloc... (cached) no
    Checking for C library tcmalloc_minimal... (cached) no
    Warning: You can get a 12% performance improvement by installing tcmalloc (libgoogle-perftools-dev package on Ubuntu
             or RedHat).
    Checking for C header file fenv.h... (cached) yes
    Checking for C header file png.h... (cached) yes
    Checking for clock_nanosleep(0,0,NULL,NULL) in C library None... (cached) yes
    Checking for C header file valgrind/valgrind.h... (cached) no
    Checking for pkg-config package hdf5-serial... (cached) no
    Checking for pkg-config package hdf5... (cached) no
    Checking for H5Fcreate("", 0, 0, 0) in C library hdf5... (cached) yes
    Checking for H5::H5File("", 0) in C++ library hdf5_cpp... (cached) yes
    Checking for C header file linux/if_tun.h... (cached) yes
    Checking for pkg-config package protobuf... (cached) yes
    Checking for GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION in C++ library protobuf... (cached) yes
    Checking for C header file linux/kvm.h... (cached) yes
    Checking for timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, NULL, NULL) in C library None... (cached) no
    Checking for timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, NULL, NULL) in C library rt... (cached) yes
    Checking size of struct kvm_xsave ... (cached) yes
    Checking for member exclude_host in struct perf_event_attr...(cached) yes
    Checking for shm_open("/test", 0, 0) in C library None... (cached) yes
    Checking for char temp; backtrace_symbols_fd((void *)&temp, 0, 0) in C library None... (cached) yes
    Checking whether __i386__ is declared... (cached) no
    Checking whether __x86_64__ is declared... (cached) yes
    Building in /home/user/gem5-21.2.1.0/build/X86
    Using saved variables file /home/user/gem5-21.2.1.0/build/variables/X86
    Checking for compiler -Wno-self-assign-overloaded support... (cached) yes
    scons: done reading SConscript files.
    scons: Building targets ...
     [VER TAGS]  -> X86/sim/tags.cc
     [    LINK]  -> X86/gem5.opt
    build/X86/base/stats/hdf5.o: In function `gem5::statistics::Hdf5::begin()':
    /home/user/gem5-21.2.1.0/build/X86/base/stats/hdf5.cc:88: undefined reference to `H5::H5File::H5File(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, H5::FileCreatPropList const&, H5::FileAccPropList const&)'
    build/X86/base/stats/hdf5.o: In function `gem5::statistics::Hdf5::appendStat(gem5::statistics::Info const&, int, unsigned long long*, double const*)':
    /home/user/gem5-21.2.1.0/build/X86/base/stats/hdf5.cc:235: undefined reference to `H5::CommonFG::openDataSet(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const'
    /home/user/gem5-21.2.1.0/build/X86/base/stats/hdf5.cc:262: undefined reference to `H5::CommonFG::createDataSet(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, H5::DataType const&, H5::DataSpace const&, H5::DSetCreatPropList const&) const'
    /home/user/gem5-21.2.1.0/build/X86/base/stats/hdf5.cc:259: undefined reference to `H5::CommonFG::getObjnameByIdx[abi:cxx11](unsigned long long) const'
    /home/user/gem5-21.2.1.0/build/X86/base/stats/hdf5.cc:265: undefined reference to `H5::Exception::getFuncName[abi:cxx11]() const'
    /home/user/gem5-21.2.1.0/build/X86/base/stats/hdf5.cc:265: undefined reference to `H5::Exception::getDetailMsg[abi:cxx11]() const'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    scons: *** [build/X86/gem5.opt] Error 1
    scons: building terminated because of errors.
    *** Summary of Warnings ***
    Warning: You can get a 12% performance improvement by installing tcmalloc (libgoogle-perftools-dev package on Ubuntu
             or RedHat).
```

Comment: Looks like your log is for an incremental build (you've built the tree before).  Can you rerun adding --verbose to your command line? Also do a full clean build and build with --verbose.

Comment: Here is the build log with --verbose option enabled

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12dx33E0bSzg3I6d30B-ph0Ki9mXjIz9l/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That link line is absolutely massive... probably there's some mismatch, e.g. is this `-L/home/user/hdf/HDF5-1.12.1-Linux/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.12.1/lib` actually the right place for the library?  You have some complaints about cxx11 standard types, but are using -std=c++17.  etc.

Comment: Try doing a `scons -c`, `rm -rf .scons_config`, `find . -name sconsign -exec rm -f {} \; ` To get a fully clean build tree,  followed by the previous scons call and try again. It's possible you have some cached configure info which is no longer valid? Barring that, you should probably ask the project directly. see: https://www.gem5.org/documentation/reporting_problems/